# Cómo pasar wordpress en local a otro ordenador

Tags: wordpress

Yo tengo una página de wordpress en mi ordenador, en local, y quiero migrar esa misma página a otro ordenador, para que ese ordenador pueda tenerla en local también. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Puede que existan varias formas de hacerlo, pero yo te recomiendo 2

1. Manualmente:
   Para ello realiza una copia de la base de datos del sitio, luego copia toda tu instalación de wordpress y muévela al nuevo servidor, crea una base de datos en el nuevo servidor e importa el archivo de la DB original, luego edita el wp-config.php de tu instalación de wordpress y modifica la información del servidor anterior por el actual, las lineas a modificar son las siguientes:

   define( 'DB_NAME', 'nombre de la base de datos' );

   define( 'DB_USER', 'usuario de la base de datos' );

   define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'contraseña de la base de datos' );

En tu base de datos ve a wp_option y cambia siteurl y home por la nueva url, con eso lo único que restaría es iniciar tu sitio, si da error prueba a eliminar el htaccess o volverlo por defecto.

2. Plugins:
   La forma mas fácil seria con un plugin como all in one migration, creas una copia y luego la importas en otra instalación de wordpress, así de fácil, el problema de esto es que por lo general estas limitado a 500MB por ejemplo, por lo que si tu sitio pesa mas no podrás migrarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias. ¿Pero esto sirve para migrar WordPress al completo desde un ordenador a otro? Todo en local, tanto en un ordenador como en otro, sin subir nada a ningún hosting.

Comment: Así es, podras tener tu instalación completa en otros servidores local o bien en un servidor en linea!!